# Exclude category from query

Tags: categories, query, exclude

### PROBLEM

Hey everyone I have the wp loop to display posts, but I need to exclude category 81.
I tried: **query_posts('cat=-81'); ?>** before the loop but the pagenavi is broken and it doesn't work properly.

### CODE

```
    <?php  if(have_posts()): ?>
                 
                <ol class="list posts">
                    
                <?php
                    $end = array(3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45);
                    $i = 0;
                    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                    $i++;
                    global $post;
                ?>
```

### HEADER

I have this in the begining of the page - maybe it has something to do with it?:

```
<?php get_header();

global $wp_query;
$curauth = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
global $query_string;
query_posts( $query_string . '&cat=-81' );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Preserving_Existing_Query_Parameters

Comment: Awesome, that worked perfectly. Will it be problem to leave the global $wp_query;
$curauth = $wp_query->get_queried_object(); along with the new global You posted? Will there be any problems in wp?

Comment: I would not expect any problems with that.

Comment: Cheers, it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work

```
$cat = ( !empty( $wp_query->get('cat') ) )
    ? wp_query('cat').',-81'
    : '-81';
$wp_query->set(
    'cat',
    $cat
);
```

But what you really want to be doing is using `tax_query` and just setting the `taxonomy` parameter to `category`.